# Continuing tally on python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with three columns. These columns contain a name and a running tally of how many times the name has appeared, and the third column is a concatenation of these two columns.

| name | count | concat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sam | 1 | sam1 |
| sylvia | 1 | sylvia1 |
| tom | 1 | tom1 |
| sam | 2 | sam2 |
| sam | 3 | sam3 |

I was able to generate the count column using the groupby and count functions. However, the challenge comes in when I later added more data to the table. I want the count to continue from the last count for the similar name irrespective of where it starts. In the next entry:

| name | original_count | new_count | concat |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sam | 11 |  | sam11 |
| sylvia | 15 |  | sylvia15 |
| tom | 11 |  | tom11 |
| sam |  | 12 | sam13 |
| tom |  | 12 | tom13 |
| sylvia |  | 16 | sylvia16 |

I've not been able to figure out a logic that can continue the count from the last count on the original list. Any help or pointers would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution I found would be to use Lag functionality of Pandas. If you already have a DataFrame with initial count and you add more data to it you can use the following:

```py
import pandas as pd

tmp = df.copy() # copy for reference and mask for 'count'
while any(pd.isna(tmp['count']):
    mask = pd.isna(tmp['count']) # get indices where no counts
    new = tmp.groupby('name')['count'].shift(1) + 1 # get last value (lag value)
                                                    # for according name
                                                    # and increase by 1
    df.loc[mask, 'new_count'] = new.loc[mask] # assigning new counts
    tmp.loc[mask, 'count'] = new.loc[mask]
print(df)
```

Your dataframe should then look something like this:

```py
     name  count  new_count
0     sam    1.0        NaN
1  sylvia    1.0        NaN
2     tom    1.0        NaN
3     sam    2.0        NaN
4     sam    3.0        NaN
5  sylvia    2.0        NaN
6     sam    NaN        4.0
7     tom    NaN        2.0
8  sylvia    NaN        3.0
9     sam    NaN        5.0
```

---

Another way would be, if it is ok for all counts being in only one column:

```py
df['count'] = df.groupby(by='name')['name'].rank("first",ascending=True).astype(int)
print(df)
```

will result in

```py
     name  count
0     sam      1
1  sylvia      1
2     tom      1
3     sam      2
4     sam      3
5  sylvia      2
6     sam      4
7     tom      2
8  sylvia      3
9     sam      5
```

This solution however does not directly "look up" the last count already in the dataframe, but always calculates them completely from the beginning